# t-sql: does hashing preserve order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hash

I need to hash a primary key on a SQL table but I need to preserve the numeric ordering.

Will the hash function `HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )` preserve such order? [function doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: No, in general, hashing does not preserve order.  In fact, that would be contrary to one of the purposes of hashing, which is masking data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to test:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                            GUID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
                            HashedID varbinary(8000) NULL,
                            HashedGUID varbinary(8000) NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
DEFAULT VALUES
GO 10

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET HashedID = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONVERT(nvarchar(32),ID)),
    HashedGUID = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONVERT(nvarchar(36),GUID));
GO

SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HashedID) AS HashedIDOrder,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HashedGUID) AS HashedGUIDOrder
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY ID ASC;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

For the results I got the answer is clear: "No".

```
ID          GUID                                 HashedIDOrder        HashedGUIDOrder
----------- ------------------------------------ -------------------- --------------------
1           8655266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 10                   5
2           8755266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 5                    7
3           8855266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 7                    9
4           8955266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 3                    4
5           8A55266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 2                    6
6           8B55266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 6                    2
7           8C55266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 9                    8
8           8D55266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 1                    10
9           8E55266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 8                    3
10          8F55266A-0054-EB11-8144-F0921C07876B 4                    1
```

Comment: You're welcome, @datapipe . If it answers the question, please do mark it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful.